# Add custom item with null value in jquery's autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using [jQuery's autotomplete widget](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), I would like to add one item if no criteria is matched. That item is added just fine but the problem I'm facing is that I can't set that item's value to `null`. what I'm getting is the item's `value` with the same text as the `label`

Sample code:

```
source: function(request, response)
{
    //suggestions prefilled via AJAX...

    var items = [];

    if(suggestions.length)
    {
        for(var i in suggestions)
        {
            var item = suggestions[i];

            item.value = suggestions[i].id;
            item.label = suggestions[i].text;

            items.push(item);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var item = {
            value : null,
            label : "some text..."
        };

        items.push(item);
    }

    response(items);
}
```

When I console the selected item, this is what I get:

```
select: function(event, ui)
{
    console.log(ui.item.value);
    //if item's value was set to null, then label
    //if item's value was set to 0, then label
    //if item's value was set to "", then label
    //if item's value was set to 123, then 123
}
```

**EDIT**: apparently this worked at some point in history...

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1r2etyf/) with latest jquery and jquery ui the problem is present, but in [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/z1r2etyf/1/) with jquery 1.10.4 was the last jquery ui that worked the way I want.

Comment: Why not use `""` versus `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, it seems to ignore it when you have 1 item in the list to select from.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6oa0yg24/2/

```
$(function() {
  var items = [{
      value: 1,
      label: 'neo'
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: 'trinity'
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      label: 'morpheus'
    },
    {
      value: null,
      label: 'smith'
    },
    {
      value: undefined,
      label: 'switch'
    },
    {
      value: "",
      label: 'tank'
    }
  ];

  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: items,
    select: function(e, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.value);
    }
  });
});
```

If we type `t`, we get a few hits, and select `smith`, the value is left empty. If we type `sm`, and now the only option is `smith`, "smith" is then added as the value. Why? I don't know, but I tested all three scenarios, and each does it. Pretty sure it comes down to these lines (5864 - 5869 in https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js):

```
// reset the term after the select event
// this allows custom select handling to work properly
this.term = this._value();

this.close( event );
this.selectedItem = item;
```

I suspect you can overwrite it with Widget Factory if you are so inclined.

Comment: _it seems to ignore it when you have 1 item in the list to select from_ good catch!! Thanks, I ended up using another key like `id` so it doesn't get affected by that reset